# Scrollable in JTextArea

Tags: java, jtextarea

I have a class extending JFrame and a JTextArea with the configuration below. For some reason my Scroll doesn not appear. I can't figure out why.

```
     JTextArea ta=new JTextArea();
         ...

            ta.setText(out);
            JScrollPane scrollFrame = new JScrollPane(ta);
            //ta.setAutoscrolls(true);
            scrollFrame.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            scrollFrame.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            add(scrollFrame);
            add(ta);
            setSize(300, 300);
            setResizable(false);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
```

For example, [Adding a Scrollable JTextArea (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849063/adding-a-scrollable-jtextarea-java)

Comment: You shouldn't be `add`ing `scrollFrame` and `ta` to your frame. Adding only `scrollFrame` should be fine since it already wraps `ta`.

Comment: Jesus, I knew it must be a silly thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add the scrollframe and not the JTextArea

```
 add(scrollFrame);
// add(ta);
```